# Why keepalived vrrp does not add virtual ip to openvpn tun0?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, keepalived

I am running two instances of keepAlived on local Haproxy node and a remote Haproxy node, the local haproxy node works just fine but for remote it doesn't add virtual ip 10.8.0.2 to the remote node.

```
vrrp_instance RH_EXT {
   state BACKUP
   interface tun0
   virtual_router_id 12
   priority 99
   advert_int 1
   authentication {
       auth_type PASS
       auth_pass keepAlived123
   }
   virtual_ipaddress {
       10.8.0.2
   }
}
```

I am also seeing this error:

```
Dec 31 19:29:36 pi4-phl Keepalived_vrrp[28178]: (RH_EXT) ip address 10.8.0.1/32 dev tun0, no longer exist
Dec 31 19:29:38 pi4-phl Keepalived_vrrp[28178]: (RH_EXT) ip address associated with VRID 12 not present in MASTER advert : 10.8.0.2
```

maybe that is when when all the local nodes are down it doesn't load balance from the remote node.